# Seafile-server search option in web

Tags: ubuntu, centos, seafile-server

I have installed Seafile server in centos and seafile client in windows machine.

Please anyone help me to clarify my doubts. I have included screenshot.

1. How to enable search bar in all pages like seacloud.cc
2. After I logged Admin account how to view user files.
3. In future how upgrade Hard disk incase if Hard disk is full.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Only available in the pro edition
2. You cannot view other users files except they have shared them with you
3. Stop server -> Copy from old disk to new disk -> update Settings for ngnix (Path to data) -> start server